# Make a video player appear when a button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I would like to make a video blog and use multiple video players, youtube and jwplayer. How would I make it so that youtube player appears by default and below it there is a button, when the button is pressed, the jwplayer appears and replaces youtube.

If anyone could tell me the code to use, that would be awesome and thanks to everyone in advance for helping!

Comment: Display the relevant source code, no source code = nothing to work with. Also displaying your attempts of doing this would be a good idea.

Comment: I have no source code, that's why I'm asking, I have also made no attempts either because because I don't know how I would do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knocked you up a simple example:

http://jsfiddle.net/xxktz511/4/

It uses this single bit of javascript and the jQuery framework to change a child element of a parent blog item. As from what you are saying you will have many blog entries on the page.

```
// Use the jQuery plugin to find all DOM element that have a class of 'switch player'
// You can read up on jquery here: http://jquery.com/
$('.switch_player').click(
    function(e) {
        // Make a jQuery instance based on the 'currentTarget' or 'click' element
        // Find that element parent that is the actual blog entry
        var $blogEntry = $(e.currentTarget).parent();        
        // Then find all children that have either a youtube_video class or
        // jqPlayer class and toggle their display status
        $blogEntry.children('.youtube_video').toggle();
        $blogEntry.children('.jwplayer_video').toggle();
    }  
);
```

If the video timing is the same then jwplayer can start a stream from a given point. It is in the documentation. However I do not know how you get the current time from youtube.

Let me know if you have any questions about the design.

Comment: Thanks for this, I can't seem to get jQuery working on my site but that method clearly works.

Comment: No problem. Easiest way to include jQuery is to add it from the google CDN. Just copy and paste the line before the code here: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery. Let me know if you would like my example in the form of a complete html doc and I will stash it somewhere for you.

Comment: If you could do that that would be really awesome!

Comment: Also, I put the code before the jquery and it didn't work: http://gyazo.com/4cff0386a9e5e40be0a2201de05248b8
(Pressing the "Switch Player" text doesn't work)

Comment: http://crikey.haveigonetoofar.com/demos/videoBlogDemo.html is the demo and here is the source:http://crikey.haveigonetoofar.com/demos/videoBlogDemo_source.txt

Comment: OK, it's working now but instead of a button, it is just text: http://gyazo.com/e6914476d7976cc738be126ed310f3a1

Comment: Make sure to take the <link> element and put that in your <head> element. Have a look at the source file for an example. This is for Bootstrap, a css framework to make the Div look like a button.

Comment: I have now run into a problem (Sorry for so many comments) Using that style sheet made the rest of my page mess up, is there a way that I can just get the code for making the text a button? Thanks

Comment: Yep but they will have no formatting you will need to add the CSS for that sorry: Demo update: http://crikey.haveigonetoofar.com/demos/videoBlogDemo.html

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like this. Warning didnt test code myself but should work.

```
    <form method="post">
    <input name="button" type="submit" />
    </form>


    <?php

    if (!empty('$_POST')){
        //jwplayer video
    }
    else{
        //youtubevideo
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: sorry smal change. remove the two '' in the if statement next to the $_POST

Comment: Reload the page just for one element?